# Display private/protected attributes in Umbrello UML modeler

Tags: kde, uml

Using Umbrello Version 2.7.4, when creating a new class, private/protected 
attributes are not shown in class diagram view while public are shown.
I have verified that show attributes option is checked. Is this a known bug ? How it could be fixed ?

Problem seems to exists since 2.4.4: http://lists.opensuse.org/archive/opensuse/2010-12/msg00011.html

Private/protected attributes should be present with a minus/tilde sign at the start of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running the latest Umbrello from SVN (as of 2012/01/20, r1274951) and you can right-click on your class and Uncheck Show->Public Only.  You can also change this setting at the diagram properties level or in the global Umbrello settings.  However, I don't know if this is available is earlier versions...

Hope this helps

Comment: Also works on non-SVN version: 
right-click the class > properties > Display > **Uncheck 'Public Only'**.

Private attribute are now be visible ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the version I am using, 2.11, you need to right-click on your class, go to properties->display and uncheck Public Only.